# PHP strtotime() and compare current time based on two given time

Tags: strtotime

I'm facing issue in comparing current time based on two pre-specified time. Let me tell what I want:
I want to display a message if current time is between 10PM to 8AM. And my code was

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ( $current_time > strtotime('10:00pm') && $current_time < strtotime('8:00am') ) { 
   //Display message
}
```

But it's not working because, after 12:00AM, strtotime('10:00pm') is calculating today's 10PM value and isn't able to pass in given condition. So I need your suggestion.

Comment: The value return from strtotime() contain data of date info,That is the actual problem

Comment: you want 10:00 pm - 8:00 AM(next day) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date("G", strtotime("now"))` will show 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros.

The code you wanted would be:

```
$current_hour = date("G", strtotime("now"));
if ($current_hour >= 22 || $current_hour < 8) {
    //Display message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
     $current_hour = date("G", strtotime("now"));
     if ($current_hour > 23 || $current_hour < 8) {
     if ( $current_time > strtotime('10:00pm -1 Day') && $current_time < strtotime('8:00am') ) { //after 
     //Display message
    }
     }else{
     if ( $current_time > strtotime('10:00pm') && $current_time < strtotime('8:00am +1 Day') ) { 
    //Display message
      }
    }
```